# React integration in Asp.Net Core : UseReact vs UseSpa

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I developped a rest API in Asp.Net Core. I am now going to develop react interface, and i would like to integrate this into my Asp.Net server, in order not to have two different servers to deploy.

When I look for on internet, I see a lot of people doing that with **UseReact** function, and adding an annotation @using React.AspNet in cshtml file.

However, I dont understand that much cshtml file (I have the feeling it's for server side rendering), and I would like to use only react "standard" architecture, to be able to develop it with people who does not code in Asp.Net

I also saw that Visual Studio skeleton for react (using create-react-app) uses UseSpa function instead of UseReact.
I managed to integrate the create-react-app in my skeleton, using UseSpa function in my Startup.Configure function, and I am trying to integrate a most complex react app.

My question is what the **differences** between **UseReact** and **UseSpa** functions ?
Can we use UseReact without cshtml files ? And can we make server rendering, and use jsx files with UseSpa function and no cshtml file ?

Thanks for your help